# can I replace nulls in a PIVOT with zeroes?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, pivot

I am using the PIVOT function in Oracle and am curious if I can replace the null values with zeroes?  I know I can wrap the entire query in another SELECT and then use COALESCE on the values, but I am curious if there is a shortcut.

Comment: `NVL(column_name,0)` ?

Comment: There is no "column" name, per se, in the PIVOT function.  This will work if I wrap the entire query; I am wondering if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 8):

If you have the following table of data that you want to pivot:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (id int, name varchar2(1), value varchar(10));

INSERT ALL 
    INTO yourtable (id, name, value )
         VALUES (1, 'A', '1500')
    INTO yourtable (id, name, value )
         VALUES (1, 'B', '4500')
    INTO yourtable (id, name, value )
         VALUES (2, 'C', '3.5')
    INTO yourtable (id, name, value )
         VALUES (3, 'B', 'test')
    INTO yourtable (id, name, value )
         VALUES (4, 'A', 'blah')
    INTO yourtable (id, name, value )
         VALUES (4, 'C', 'hello')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

And your current code is similar to:

```
select id, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC
from
(
  select id, name, value
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for name in ('A' as OptionA, 'B' OptionB, 'C' OptionC)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69393/6).  The sample data will create `null` values.

When you want to replace the `null` values you have to do it in the final `SELECT` list. So your code will need to be:

```
select id, 
  coalesce(OptionA, '0') OptionA, 
  coalesce(OptionB, '0') OptionB, 
  coalesce(OptionC, '0') OptionC
from
(
  select id, name, value
  from yourtable
)
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for name in ('A' as OptionA, 'B' as OptionB, 'C' as OptionC)
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69393/7)

Comment: So you are wrapping the pivot query and using coalesce like described by the OP in the question. Perhaps you also want to address the 2nd part - i.e. ' ... curious if there is a shortcut.'